# datagrid column does not update

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

I have a WPF form with a DataGrid. This DG contains a DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a ComboBox. When I click on the new row of the DG and selected a value from the Combobox and then tab to the next column, the selected value does not stay visible in the combobox column.

However, when I tab back, the correct value shows in the combobox.

How do I keep the selected value showing in the combobox column when I tab off the column?

Here is my comboxbox column xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type" Width="160">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocationType.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Name="cboAddrtype"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtAddrType}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.LocationTypesObject, Mode=OneTime}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLocationType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LocationTypeKey, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedValuePath="InternalKey"
                      Width="100" />

        </StackPanel>

    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Comment: Why do you have both a `SelectedItem` and a `SelectedValue`? They're different ways of setting the same property. I'd suggest getting rid of `SelectedItem` because it compares the item by reference, not value, and because you have a `OneWay` binding on it.

Comment: Update. I changed the selected item to LocationType and now it works. In my case, I need both the SelectedItem and the SelectedValue in order for things to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CellTemplate` you're binding `LocationType.Description` and in `CellEditingTemplate` you're binding `SelectedLocationType` and `LocationTypeKey`. I'm not sure that your binding from `ComboBox` won't somehow affect `LocationType.Description`.

Furthermore, `SelectedLocationType` and `LocationTypeKey` are not in the context of `DataTemplate`. You should add a `Source` binding property to get your ViewModel.